# CSS line-break or/and ellipsis depending on parent dimensions

Tags: html, css, text, overflow, whitespace

Please take a look at the following code snippet:

```or-tag-here
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

I would like to aim 3 main scenarios, in every case the width of `parent` is less than the width of the `child`:

1. If the height of `parent` allows, I would like to **break the line**.
2. If the height of `parent` doesn't allow to break the line than I would like to truncate with **ellipsis**.
3. If the height of `parent` allows to break the line, but after **n** lines I reached the maximum height but still have some text to show than use **ellipsis**.

Please note that the dimensions of `parent` are dynamic, depending on higher level and sibling elements.

**Solution 1**: The first case is solved automatically (+ `white-space: break-spaces;`) 
**Solution 2**: Applying the `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` solved the second scenario.

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mihocsa48/pen/KKEgyNO?editors=1100)!

The question is the 3rd case: how is it possible to decide which to apply? The **Solution 1**, **Solution 2** or both of them depending on `parent` dimensions?

Comment: you are talking about the height of the parent but that height is defined by its content

Comment: Not exactly. The height of the `parent` depends on multiple other elements, like siblings and/or higher level elements.

Comment: That set of requirements isn't solvable using current CSS. You will need to involve JavaScript, to "take measurements", and then decide how to handle the situation.

Comment: *The height of the parent depends on multiple other elements, like siblings and/or higher level elements.* --> That's not part of your question so no one can guess it. Your question need to contain all the requirements and detail. Share a "real" code not a "sample" code that doesn't reflect your real situation.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, I already have a working JS based solution, I just thought to would be better to leave JS out of the game if possible. I already read similar opinions so It seems like the JS solution is the winner.

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you take a closer look to the question there is a line where I specified: _Please note that the width of parent is dynamic, depending on higher level and sibling elements._
Some lines later I linked a Codepen example, could that be called as a "real" code?

Comment: That's the "width" not the "height". Two different things.

Comment: My bad. I meant the dimensions, width and height as well.

Comment: @TemaniAfif now that we clarified the misunderstanding, what do you think? Is it possible to solve the problem with pure CSS or not?